# Python scripts gives different results when run through Task scheduler

Tags: python, win32com

I created a batch file to run a python script. The script runs fine when I run it by double clicking the batch file but gives me different result when I run it through the task scheduler. The script is as follows:

```
import datetime    
import win32com.client
import os
import pandas as pd
import urllib
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

path = os.path.expanduser("//server/drive/folder")

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6) 


messages = inbox.Items
run_date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%m-%d-%Y")

message = messages.GetLast()

while message.SentOn.strftime("%m-%d-%Y") == run_date:
    if message.Subject.find("Some Subject") >= 0:
    for attachment in message.Attachments:
        if(attachment.FileName.find("xlsx") >= 0): 
        attachment.SaveAsFile(os.path.join(path, str(attachment)))
        FileToUpload = os.path.join(path, str(attachment))
        FileName = str(attachment)
        MessageToMove = message
    message = messages.GetPrevious()

log=[]

MessageToMove.Move(outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders("Done Folder"))

log.append(run_date)
log.append(message.Subject)
log_file = open("//server/drive/folderLog.txt", 'w')
for item in log: nodis=log_file.write("%s\n" % item)
log_file.close()
```

I am doing a few more things in the script which are irrelevant to this situation.

The double click works correctly and only compares the emails I received today, and the 'message' is the first message of yesterday, but the task scheduler compares till the last email I have in my outlook ('message' is the last email in my outlook).
Any idea why this is happening. I searched a few questions but I could not find an answer/solution to my situation.

Update:in the task scheduler, it directly takes the last message of my Outlook inbox.

Comment: I do something similar and dont face the problem. Can you compare os.environ by logging the env variables to a file in each case?

Comment: I logged a few more things.Firstly the code is directly jumping to the very last email in my outlook. I compared the OS environment as you said. There were 3 differences 1st is Task scheduler and other batch.For the task scheduler, ';' was missing here.`;C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps',` and `;C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps;',`
Path was as follows`, 'PSMODULEPATH': '%ProgramFiles%\\WindowsPowerShell\\Modules;`,`, 'PSMODULEPATH': 'C:\\Program Files\\WindowsPowerShell\\Modules;`and this was missing in Scheduler`, 'SESSIONNAME': 'Console',`

Comment: Ok so this is what I see. When I run the script in batch file, the last message `messages.GetLast()` is the most recent message. When I run in through the Task scheduler the last message is the Last message in my outlook. Any idea why?